# GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()

Tags: gwt, exception

Has anyone successfully used the above statement to catch the exception before it goes to the browser as an alert?.

I registered a custom Exception Handler in the first line of my application entry point. But it does not catch the exception as expected.

```
public void onModuleLoad(){
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
    ...
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**

Here are my two classes:

I expect my system.out will print the details of the exception 
and exception will be swallowed and should not be sent to browser.

Or Am I wrong?

```
package mypackage;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ClientExceptionHandler());
    startApplication();
    }

    private void startApplication() {
    Integer.parseInt("I_AM_NOT_NUMBER");
    }
}
```

---

```
package mypackage;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

public class ClientExceptionHandler implements GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void onUncaughtException(Throwable cause) {
    System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `MyExceptionHandler` do?  Have you tried using a debugger to see if the exception makes it to your handler?

Comment: From the javadocs: "In hosted mode, the default handler prints a stack trace to the log window. In web mode, the default handler is null and thus exceptions are allowed to escape, which provides an opportunity to use a JavaScript debugger." Have you checked if this default handler is indeed set? And maybe try to unset it via `GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(null);` and *then* try setting yours (I know it doesn't sound too smart, but maybe it's a bug in GWT and the default handler is not properly "unset").

Comment: Dear Jason,

MyExceptionHandler is an implementation of GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler. The program flow did not reach the  onUncaughtException(Throwable cause) method at all.

Comment: Dear Igor,

Unsetting with <pre>null</pre> and setting with my custom UncaughtExceptionHandler did not help. It is the same problem.

Comment: setUncaughtExceptionHandler() does work. Instead of describing what isn't happening, can you describe what is happening? And if you can provide a code snippet that reproduces the problem you're having, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is that the current JS event cycle is using the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler because that was the handler set at the start of the cycle. You'll need to defer further initialization to the next event cycle, like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ClientExceptionHandler());
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
           startApplication();
           Window.alert("You won't see this");
        }
    });
}

private void startApplication() {
    Integer.parseInt("I_AM_NOT_A_NUMBER");
    // or any exception that results from server call
}
```

**Update:** And [here's the issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1617) that describes why this works, and why it isn't planned to be fixed.

Comment: When I run my app I see the "You won't see this" text why?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a default handler can be a tricky proposition some times.  I can tell you exactly what is going on.  If you get an exception in the onModuleLoad(), the handler will not be called.  It is only after the load method is completed that it will ACTUALLY get put into place.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
public void onModuleLoad(){
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        onUncaughtException(Throwable t) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: If the OP's `MyExceptionHandler` implements `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, then I don't see how this should matter.

Comment: Dear Jeroen,

I did try the anonymous version as suggested earlier. But the problem remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Silly solution, but it works fine!
before anything add your EntryPoint in your app.gwt.xml

```
<entry-point class='myPackage.client.MyEntryPoint' />
```

then;

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    private EventBus eventBus;
    @Inject
    public MyEntryPoint(final EventBus eventBus){
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler customUncaughtExceptionHandler = new CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(customUncaughtExceptionHandler);
        try {
            onModuleLoad2();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            eventBus.fireEvent(new BusyEvent(false));
            customUncaughtExceptionHandler.onUncaughtException(ex);
        }

    }

    private void onModuleLoad2() {
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
}
```

and your CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler would be something like:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
public class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        Throwable exceptionToDisplay = getExceptionToDisplay( e );
         Window.alert( exceptionToDisplay.getCause() .getMessage()+"    "+ exceptionToDisplay.getStackTrace());

    }
    private static Throwable getExceptionToDisplay( Throwable throwable ) {
         Throwable result = throwable;
         if (throwable instanceof UmbrellaException && ((UmbrellaException) throwable).getCauses().size() >= 1) {
             result = ((UmbrellaException) throwable).getCauses().iterator().next();
         }
         return result;
    }

}
```