# Multiple javascript exception handling in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, exception, gwt

I wonder how people usually do to handle multiple exception from javascript in GWT? for example, this method from the [IndexedDB specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IDBObjectStore#add):

IDBRequest add( in any value, in optional any key ) raises (IDBDatabaseException, DOMException);

It can raise two JavaScript exception objects, so i have no idea how to implement wrapper for it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the java's try catch to catch javascriptexception. it works well :)

Answer (score 1):

There exist an

```
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ClientExceptionHandler());
```

Its already discribed here:
[GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028521/gwt-setuncaughtexceptionhandler)

I don't think I have to add anything :)