# Remote debugging with screen capture

Tags: user-interface, gwt, tomcat7

I wanted to know if there is java libray or framework to enables remote debugging via screen capture .

The application  is developped in  GWT running on tomcat.
What i want is , whenever any exception happens a screen shot is taken of the UI where the error is located . Or the user can also  report it by clicking on a button on the same screen .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I guess it's possible, but you have to program a solution yourself ( I don't know any existing solution) :

To catch every **client side** Exception, use [setUncoughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028521/gwt-setuncaughtexceptionhandler). At this point I can recommend [gwt-log](https://github.com/fredsa/gwt-log), which is easily set up and can be used to send all client side Exceptions to your Server, where they can be logged.
But you have to combine both, because you need an event which triggers the image creation and the sending of the exception to the server. This is because you can either use `setUncoughtExceptionHandler` or attach gwt-log to your client.
Alternative you can do it without gwt-log and then send both by yourself (image and exception) at the same time to the server, to store them combined.

To get a screenshot you can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com), which renders something like a screenshot out of the DOM.

All in all I expect it will take some time to set up and programm all parts of the solution, but in the end it should work.

Comment: As you said need to combine log,exception and screen capture. But it will work i am confident . Thanks