# GWT exception handling

Tags: exception, serialization, gwt, rpc

How can I avoid or customize exception messages shown in the network tab of chrome developer tool?

If oracle sends back an error we don't want to print the error on the client browser developer tool. How can I use serialization exception handling to customize the exception? How can I catch the exception before it reaches the client browser?

> org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds@1663f519
>
> Details:
> Error querying database.
> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator ORA-0651

This error is visible in Network Tab of developer tool.

Comment: How about letting us know what the exception looks like you are talking about?

Comment: As of now exception looks like : org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds@1663f519\n\tDetails: \n### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator\nORA-0651     -- this error is visible in Network Tab of developer tool.  How can we custyimze this message shown in dev tool ?

Comment: Try to set uncaught exception handler. [Maybe this post will help You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028521/gwt-setuncaughtexceptionhandler)

Comment: I would expect to catch these kind of exception on the server and throw a new exception and handle this exception on the client side.